# Passing pointer to a struct?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

Hello I'm trying to pass data from a pointer to a struct but the values seem to be different.

```
struct somestruct
{
    public file header;
    public uint version;
}

unsafe struct file
{
    public fixed char name[8];
    public uint type;
    public uint size;
}
```

Then in code somewhere..

```
public unsafe int ReadFile(string filepath)
{
    somestruct f = new somestruct();
    byte[] fdata = System.IO.ReadAllBytes( filepath );
    fixed( byte* src = fdata )
    {
        f.header = *(file*)src;
        MessageBox.Show( new string(f.header.name) ); //should be 'FILENAME' but it's like japanese.
    }
    return 0;
}

Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  46 49 4C 45 4E 41 4D 45 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 30  FILENAME.......0
00000010  74 27 9F EF 74 77 F1 D7 C5 86 93 3D 39 0D 72 A9  t'Ÿïtwñ×Å†“=9.r©
00000020  63 8B 92 CF F6 7D 8A 14 45 9D 68 51 A4 8E A4 EE  c‹’Ïö}Š.E.hQ¤Ž¤î
00000030  4E FE D0 66 45 0E C9 8D 96 BB F4 EE 52 1F 89 D3  NþÐfE.É.–»ôîR.‰Ó
00000040  5C 80 1A 71 8A 16 B1 8B 3A A8 1B A4 48 11 B8 E8  \€.qŠ.±‹:¨.¤H.¸è
```

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why are you solving this with pointers?

Comment: because pointers are faster, and use less code to add to a struct. It's one of the reasons I prefer C++ over C#, but I wanted to do C# for this project. :)

Answer (score 3):

Each `char` is 2 bytes - a fixed buffer of 8 chars is 16 bytes. You are reading the first 8 bytes as only the first 4 characters in that buffer, and the high bytes will make it look. Like the eastern Unicode ranges.

I would say: deserialize it at the stream level. Don't do this.

Basically, read (at least) 20 bytes into a buffer, then decode manually, using:

```
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 8);
```

For the string, and probably shift operations for the unsigned integers.

You could also use `unsafe` code to read the integers from the buffer, via the other meaning of `fixed` and a pointer-cast.

Comment: I got it figured out, I just converted the byte* to byte[] and used Encoding.ASCII.GetString. (like above), thanks for all the help guys. Seems kinda dumb that a char is 2 bytes instead of 1. :/

Comment: @user if it seems "dumb", then that mean's you aren't clear on what `char` *is* - it is a utf-16 **unicode** character - `wchar` to you. If you want 8 bit data, use `byte[]` or similar.

Comment: +1. @user1594121 agree that `char` as 2 bytes is not optimal. 4 would be so much simple... But we have to live with surrogate pair instead. :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm just used to C/C++ where char is a byte. Maybe they should rename that type xD

Comment: @user1594121 well, since `struct` means something fundamentally different *too*, maybe they should do that at the same time ;p

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is UTF-16 and is 2 bytes.  You need to convert the UTF-8/ANSI (1 byte) string to a UTF-16 string.